# datepicker in jquery

Tags: jquery

can anyone tell me link to learn how to make datepicker in jquery

Comment: 10 questions and you have not selected any answers? Why should people help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to make your own?

jQueryUI already provide quite a good tool:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

That is what I use over many many sites now, works very well and had localisation support..